# Storing recorded calls into Google Voice

Tags: google-voice

I don't use Google Voice but I'd like to store recorded phone calls into Google Voice.

I was thinking of writing an app that you allow you to store audio files into Google Voice so that you can transcribe it and index and search it.

Is this possible or is it limited to the fact that only calls stored there are the one you would make using Google Voice?

Thanks

---

Clarification: I got this idea after looking an app on the Android Play Store that lets you copy all your SMSs/MMSs to your Gmail inbox using IMAP and you'll be able to view all your conversations right in your inbox. I was thinking that if it was possible to record some calls and also move call logs into Google Voice, that would be pretty neat. However, this would be a separate app and nothing to calling and texting using Google Voice.

Answer (score 1):

While putting things into google voice probably isn't going to work out well, you can still leverage their power. The google speech recognition api is publicly accessible although mostly undocumented, and you can see a tutorial on an example usage in this demonstration on making your own siri here: http://cranklin.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/building-my-own-siri-jarvis/

You can learn more about the api here:

http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

Have fun.

Comment: Hi Gmline, have look at my edit. I've clarified a little bit more about what I've been trying to achieve.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla If I recall there is a very very complicated way to get your messages into the voice mail box of google it involves setting up asterisk and using the google voice number as a trunk.  SMS is easy as it has an email gateway for most numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways , not so for voicemail.  The most you could do is run the speach thorugh the api and then email it, though I don't know how large messages would work if that email went to a sms gateway.